# React Formik <FieldArray/> error: Uncaught Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am new to react and formik form library and I am working with `<FieldArray/>` API of formik. To give you a big picture I am having two `<FieldArray/>`s, nested. The inner `<FieldArray/>` is conditionally rendered. When it is not rendered everything looks fine but when state changes and it is going to be rendered, the app crashes and the error pops up:

> Uncaught Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

And again the next error message showing up in the console is:

> The above error occurred in the `<FieldArrayInner>` component:

The `<FieldArrayInner>` component is not my inner array component, it's just one of built in components in Formik, I guess. I am not using any components named `<FieldArrayInner>.`
One thing to note is that the inner `<FieldArray/>` (my component) works fine when it's alone (not nested).

This is the inner `<FieldArray/>`:

```jsx
        <FieldArray name={`mainArray[${subarrayIndex}].titleLink`}>
          {({ push, remove }) =>
            values.mainArray[subarrayIndex].titleLink.map(
              (titleLinkItem, index) => (
                <Row
                  key={`mainArray[${subarrayIndex + 1}].titleLink${index + 1}`}
                >
                   code ...
                </Row>
         </FieldArray>
```

And this is the outer :

```jsx
         <FieldArray name="mainArray">
            {({ push, remove }) =>
              values.mainArray.map((mainItem, index) => (
                <Row key={`mainArray[${index + 1}]`}>
                  code ...
                  {showArray ? <InnerArray> : null}
                </Row>
         </FieldArray>
```

I searched the web and specially stackoverflow.com, didn't help. Asked the AI, didn't help. When I remove the `<FieldArray>` tag around the code in the inner array, the code works fine. Right now it's just that I don't know where in the code is generating the error, otherwise it would have been much easier to debug.